# web api: get invalid fields from the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, model-validation

Is there a way to relate the error from the `Modelstate.Values` with the invalid fields from the model?

I have something like

```
foreach (var error in this.ModelState.Values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(error.Errors);
}
```

But this code returns only errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can get both the error messages and their associated parameters from the ModelState and store them in a key-value pairs by:

```
var Errors = ModelState.Keys.Where(i => ModelState[i].Errors.Count > 0)
.Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(k, ModelState[k].Errors.First().ErrorMessage));
```

This Linq query first checks and selects only the parameters that have errors and from those parameters we want to select both the parameter name and its associated error message which we store in key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

ModelState is just a Dictionary with Key and Value pairs. So it you wanted to get the property and its associated errors you would do:

```
foreach (var modelError in ModelState)
{
    string propertyName = modelError.Key;
    if (modelError.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

> error.Errors.SelectMany(x => x.ErrorMessage)

in case you need to get the error messages out.
(You would need reference to **System.Linq**)

Comment: but I needed a connection between the error and the invalid parameter